# Serializer for sealed interface (kotlinx.serialization)

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I am trying to serialize my base class that is implementing two sealed interfaces. I have tried multiple approaches, yet i always get the error :

> caused by: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Class 'PayloadFromBuilder' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'Payload'.
> Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.

I was following mostly this guide [Kotlinx/polymorphism](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/polymorphism.md) and checked some similar questions here.

My code:

```
sealed inteface MyClass {
dataetc
}

@Serializable
private class DefaultMyClass(dataetc): MyClass

fun MyClass(dataetc): MyClass = DefaultMyClass


Sealed interface MyClassBuilder {
    fun dataetc(value: ByteArray)
    fun dataetc(value: ByteArray)
    fun dataetc(value: ByteArray?)
}

@PublishedApi
@Serializable
@SerialName("payload")
internal class MyClassFromBuilder: MyClassBuilder, MyClass {

}

//Serialization
val module = SerializersModule {
  polymorphic(MyClass::class) {
        subclass(MyClassFromBuilder::class, MyClassFromBuilder.serializer())
        default { MyClassFromBuilder.serializer() }
    }

  polymorphic(MyClassBuilder::class) {
         subclass(MyClassFromBuilder::class, MyClassFromBuilder.serializer())
         default { MyClassFromBuilder.serializer() }
     }

}


val ConfiguredProtoBuf = ProtoBuf { serializersModule = module }


@ExperimentalSerializationApi
internal inline fun <reified T> ProtoBuf.encodeToMessage(value: T): Message =
    Message(encodeToByteArray(value))
```

From what i have seen i think i am very close to the solution yet i am missing something, since my example is very generic if you need more info let me know, thank you in advance.

Note: In my several tries i have tried to annotate both sealed intefaces with @Polymorphic but i am not sure if it changed anything.

Note 2: My code breaks when i am calling the encodeToMessage fun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i messed big time, turns out i was not using my ConfiguredProtoBuf when i was calling my encodeToMessage